# How to make multiple pages in only one form using C#

Tags: c#, forms

I got a project to make an ABC-book.
I have done so that when i press a button i hide my form1 and then open form2, then i can open form3 and form2 gets closed. This is only for test as you can see.

What i have tried to find on the internet is that i would like to instead of opening form after form for every character in the alphabet, i want it to just change appearence. My teacher said it's possible but wont help me since i need to get information on my own.

Is that possible to like have several designs for one form? If so, how do i open a new one and then call from the first design to the other.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: you can use `Tabs` or `Panels`

Comment: Easy to use [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) with Dock to Full. Do design on each panel and hide/show based on requirement

Comment: Or if you don't have to code something about the book content , use images and change them after you click change page.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty except panels can get very messy if you happen to move one and it suddenly becomes a child of another panel, or if you need to edit controls or add new ones. Personally I wouldn't use that at all.  Tab pages, as mentioned by Sudhakar Tillapudi, would be best.  The OP could even make them visible / invisible as necessary.

Comment: Please define "Change Appeareance"

Comment: You can also use UserControls. Remove old UC from form children, add new UC to form children.

Comment: The thing is that i need to think new, come up with a new design. Of course i had a new design right after that but i had no clue of how to make it. My idea was to have the first form, this form was the first page and had like the bookstripes to the left that hold a real book together. When i click a button the book opens up (with effect would be cool) and then the book becomes twice as big with the bookstripes in the middle. Getting that effect probably is way too hard.

Comment: But when i tried having multiple forms a glitch accourd (usererror). I ran the program. Form1 opened, i clicked a button, form2 opend and form 1 got hidden. I click the button again and form2 get's closed with the code "this.Close();" and when i exit form 3 with the crossign in the top right corner i got a code that when the form get's closed, show form1 and then i can close form1 as well. The thing is is that in my task manager the program was still running, even if i closed the final form1. My friend had the same issue, in the end i had 6 open and sometimes it said process already running.

Comment: So i don't need to have so i only use 1 form, that was only a way i thought the glitch could be fixed. But do you guys know a good video because i can't ask for code in that way here, it is wrong to ask people to do parts of the coding. But if you know anything it would be great, sorry though but i literally suck at C# (coding in generall) so I got a hard time understanding the things you say i could do :s

Answer (score 0):

I would create the pages as controls/components and create/destroy the controls with using only one form which will be the parent container. The controls/pages types be can be added to a List to be used to navigate using reflection to create the pages based on the current list/page index.

Comment: It sounds good but the thing is that I am really bad at using Visual Studio C# so i was wondering, do you know any good video that i can check out that explains what you wrote?

Answer (score -1):

You could for example [toggle the Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , the example shows that for buttons, but you could do it for whole layout that fills the screen.